# Cassandra count query takes longer time

Tags: cassandra

***Cassandra*** count query takes longer time because of million of data in the KeySpace ... increased the timeout value in caasandra.yaml also ... is there any way to improve the efficiency??  Suggestions please ..

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT COUNT(*)` is an expensive operation in Cassandra because it will scan all the nodes.

Try this tool, it is optimized for counting rows: https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-count

Comment: purpose of getting count from cassandra is need to update the relatime data count to end-user .. is this tool getting a real fast result for that ???

Comment: With a distributed database, there is no "fast" way of counting number of rows. What you could do is to use Cassandra counter types and batch updates the counts so that getting an estimate of total number of rows is very fast